# Is OpenId easier or harder for users?

Tags: openid

I'm wondering if I should use OpenId for my website.  My first exposure to OpenId was StackOverflow, and I found it confusing that they only had a login link, yet no register link.  Now that I've learned about OpenId though I prefer it over the regular way of registration.

I have a feeling that only a small percentage of the internet users know how to login with a third party account provider, and most would prefer just to create an account.  It makes sense for StackOverflow to use OpenId since the target audience is tech-savvy, however my website caters to the general public.

Does anyone have any statistics or first hand experience with using OpenId versus regular registration?

Comment: I'm not a fan personally. The only site I use it for is SO, so it is just more work for me.

Comment: strictly speaking, not programming related.

Comment: Sure it is; he is trying to make a decision on whether or not to implement it on his own site.

Comment: How can you tell if an OpenId website is an OpenId website or if it's just phishing for your gmail address and password?

Comment: Just the dark green address bar which most users don't even look at :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think these days a lot of sites have facebook login and a lot more people know how to use facebook than openid. If I were you I'd go with facebook. e.g. dailymile.com

Comment: Just tried out facebook connect for the first time on that site you provided, pretty nice i must say :)

Answer (score 1):

You should have it only as option, not requirement. People just don't understand this concept and often don't trust it.

Many stackexchange.com clients (hosted stackoverflow) have learned this hard way. There have been so many complaints that stackexchange.com developers had to implement traditional username/password authentication as an addition to existing OpenID method.

Answer (score 0):

Several members of the [OpenID Foundation](http://openid.net/foundation/sponsoring-members/) have done that sort of user experience testing.  I don't know, however, which (if any) of them have published that research.  It's certainly the sort of thing that the Foundation *should* make available, as they [make some claims](http://openid.net/add-openid/) and it'd be nice to see the numbers behind them.  Ask 'em?